# Folland theorem 6.19 proof doubt

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lp-spaces

Consider the following fragment from Folland's real analysis book:

[image]

They mention theorem 6.14, which is the following theorem:

[image]

However, to apply theorem 6.14, shouldn't we check that if $h(x)= \int_Y f(x,y)d\nu(y)$, then $\int_A |h| d\mu<\infty $ for every $A \in \mathcal{M}$ with $\mu(A) < \infty$? My question is, in other words, how is theorem 6.14 applied? Note that we may assume that the right hand side of the inequality we want to prove is finite, and this ensures that the supremum in theorem 6.14 is finite. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: By the way, this inequality can be proved simply via Jensen's inequality in essentially the same way the ordinary Minkowski's inequality is proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to check this condition since you use theorem 6.14 with $f=g$ from 6.19, $g(x)=\int f(x,y) d\nu(y)$ from 6.19 and $q=p$ from 6.19.

Comment: I find your answer unclear. Before applying theorem 6.14, I need to check that its conditions are fulfilled. Your answer does not seem to adress this...

Comment: The condititions are fulfilled as i said.. $x\mapsto t(x):=\int f(x,y)d\nu(y)$ is a measurable function on X such that $ts\in L^1$ for all $s$ which vanish outside a set a finite measure by just using your inequality (such s is in $L^q$)

Comment: I see now. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Define $$h(x) = \int_{Y}f(x,y)d\nu(y).$$ We claim that we can assume $h \in L^p(\mu).$ Indeed, otherwise we can truncate the function $f$ so that $h$ is in $L^p$ and then use a monotone convergence type argument. Then you can use that the map $$ L : L^p(\mu) \to L^q(\mu)^*$$ is an isometry (basically the content of 6.14) to conclude $$ \Vert h \Vert_{L^p(\mu)} = \Vert L(h) \Vert_{Op} \leq \int_{Y}\bigg(\int_{X}f(x,y)^p d\mu(x)\bigg)^\frac{1}{p} d\nu(y).$$ Some more details on the trucation: define $f_{k} = \min(f,k)$ and pick using sigma-finiteness sets of finite measure $X_{n}$ increasing to $X$, $Y_{n}$ increasing to $Y$, and then we get by the first part: $$\bigg(\int_{X_{n}}\bigg(\int_{ Y_{m} } f_{k}(x,y)d\nu\bigg)^p d\mu \bigg)^\frac{1}{p} \leq \int_{Y_{m}}\bigg(\int_{X_{n}}f_{k}(x,y)^p d\mu(x)\bigg)^\frac{1}{p} d\nu(y).$$ Use monotone convergence to take $k\to \infty$, then $n \to \infty$, then $ m \to \infty.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, on second thought, I think the truncation argument is actually not necessary. Actually everything is satisfied to apply theorem 6.14 by the work that has already been done!